Action of $O(3,\mathbb{R})$ on the conic $\{x^2+y^2+z^2=0\}$
The action of the orthogonal group $O(3,\mathbb{R})$ on the conic
$C= \{ x^2+y^2+z^2=0 \}$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ must be well-understood, but I could not find any reference.
Is it doubly transitive?

Dima: is $\mathbb{P}^2=\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$?

Certainly - otherwise it would be action on an empty set...

Then the action can't be doubly transitive: the stabilizer of a point is one-dimensional, so it can't be transitive on $C$ minus a point. In fact, the action can be conjugated to the standard action of $O_3(\mathbb{R})$ on $S^2\cong C$.

... more precisely, the action restricted to $SO_3$. Note also that the restriction to $SO_3$ determines everything as the action factorizes through $O_3/\pm I\cong SO_3$.

Do you know how this translates to the action on the local coordinates of $C$ ?

Not sure I understand the question. But here is a way to make the action explicit: identify $C$ with $\mathbb{P}^1$ via stereographic projection. Then $U_2$ acts on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ by fractional linear transformations. This action factorizes through $U_2/\pm I=SO_3(\mathbb{R})$.

In $U_2$, the stabilser of a projective point is 2-dimensional (isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^*$.

Dima: the stabilizer in $U_2$ of a point is closed, hence compact. It can't be $\mathbb{C}^*$.

indeed - it turns out to act on the projective points as $S^1$, as I explicitly computed in my answer. Thanks.

One possible point of confusion is that I write $U_2$ instead of $SU_2$ in my comment above. In $U_2$, the stabilizer is indeed 2-dimensional and contains the center. But is is the action of $SU_2$ that we're after.

It is not doubly transitive. It is actually very easy to see if one works with an explicit parametrisation $\rho:\mathbb{P}^2\to \mathbb{P}^3$ of the conic: $(u:v)\mapsto (2ixy:i(u^2-v^2):u^2+v^2)$. It's a 2 to 1 map, as $(-u:-v)$ maps to the same point in $\mathbb{P}^2$, and due to this, somewhat unexpectedly, complex conjugation $\sigma$ in $u,v$-coordinates is of order 4, given by $(u:v)\mapsto  \sigma(u:v)=(-\overline{v}:\overline{u})$. In terms of $u,v$, $O(3,\mathbb{R})$ is the $\rho$-image of $H:=\{g\in GL(2)| g\sigma=\sigma g\}$, that is, $H=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-\overline{b}&\overline{a}\end{pmatrix}\in GL(2)\right\}$.
From the form of $H$ it is immediate that it is transivite, but not doubly transitive, as the stabiliser of a point, say, of $(1:0)$, equals
$H_1:=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&\overline{a}\end{pmatrix}\in H\right\}$, and so it maps $(1:v)$ to $(1:v\frac{\overline{a}}{a})$, i.e. it preserves the norm of $v$. Therefore the orbit representatives of $H_1$ are $(0:1)$ and $(1:r)$, with $r\geq 0$.
